# Set fixed BSSID in LineageOS16 / Android

Tags: wi-fi, adb, mac-address

I'm searching for a way to set the BSSID my OnePlus One (running LineageOS 16) is connecting to. I started adb shell as root and tried to change the BSSID in `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`, but when restarting the WiFi connection, the *.xml file gets set to default.

Can someone tell me which file needs to be edited that the MAC Address of the BSSID may get written to the *.xml file, or in which format the change needs to be made so that it won't get set to default?

EDIT:

I found a [configuration documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration#BSSID) which tells about editing a Public String, but I don't know what needs to be edited and how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have noticed that to manually edit the XML file in newer versions of Android, you have to first turn Wi-Fi off, edit `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`, delete `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml.encrypted-checksum` and then reboot and turn Wi-Fi on again. Then it should not revert back to default. However, I have not been able to confirm this works on all devices, so make sure you backup the `/data/misc/wifi` folder along with all permissions to restore everything in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would give it a try before I know what creates the *.xml file. But I'm not sure about the format I have to use. My WifiConfigStore.xml looks like this:  `<string name="ConfigKey">&quot;MYSSID&quot;WPA_PSK</string>
<string name="SSID">&quot;MYSSID&quot;</string>
<null name="BSSID" />
<string name="PreSharedKey">&quot;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&quot;</string>`  and I'm not sure about the `null name`, while the other entries which are used are using `string name`. Do I have to edit the `null name`?

Comment: You have to replace `<null name="BSSID" />` with `<string name="BSSID">a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6</string>` (Don't forget to add the closing `</string>` tag otherwise you'll break the XML)

Comment: That sadly doesn't do the trick. The phone won't connect to the access point when using the changed *.xml file...